# Convert LinkedHasmap to POJO?

Tags: java, jaxb, resteasy, pojo

I have a POJO called `Container` which I want to send to RESTful web service.

**Client side**:

```
    try {

       JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Container.class}, null);             
       jsonContent = objectToJSON(ctx, cont);
       HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(jsonContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       ((HttpPost) httpUriRequest).setEntity(entity);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     public String objectToJSON(JAXBContext ctx, Object object)
            {
                try
                {
                    Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();

                    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
                    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
                    marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);

                    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
                    marshaller.marshal(object, sw);

                    return sw.toString();
                }
                catch (JAXBException e){

                    System.out.println("--------JAXB EXCEPTION------------\n" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    LOGGER.error("JAXB marshalling error!", e);
                }
                return "HELLO";
            }
```

I am using REST-easy.

**Server side**

```
@POST

    @Consumes({"application/json"})
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public String handlePostRequest(Object resource) {

       System.out.println("\nINSIDE HANDLE POST: CONTENT CLASS" + resource.getClass());
       System.out.println("\nINSIDE HANDLE POST: " + resource);
        return "SIDD";
    }
```

Here I recieve the content sent as `Object` type :
 `public String handlePostRequest(Object resource) {`

So SOP prints the class as `LinkedHashMap` and the attributes of my POJO (`Container`) are set in the HashMap as key value pair.

Here I want to use `Object` type as my POJOs being sent from client can differ between requests. So I want to write a generic function.

Now, is there a standard way to convert `LinkedHashMap` (coming as Object) to my POJO in java ??

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your map object in a POJO like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyResource {
  @JsonProperty("map")
  private Map<Integer,Object> map;  // or LinkedHashMap if you want

  // You can have other fields here
}
```

Your method signature would look like this:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public String handlePostRequest(MyResource resource) {
   // Access your map
   resource.getMap();
}
```

`JacksonJaxbJsonProvider` does the marshalling & unmarshalling for you. The input to your RESTful service would look like this:

```
{
"map": {
    "1" : "Hello",
    "2" : "World",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: In this case what will the client code be?? For example currently I do:  `JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContextFactory.createContext(new Class[] {Container.class}, null);             
       jsonContent = objectToJSON(ctx, cont);`. This provides a json string of `Container` class

Comment: You can use the `GsonBuilder` from `com.google.gson` to convert an Object into JSON; something like `new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(yourObject)`. Then give this JSON to the request body.